# What is the maximum open files limit?

Tags: arch-linux, limit

I'm working on a reasonably large project, and recently had to bump the `nofile` setting above 500,000. I tried to [change it to five million in /etc/security/limits.d/99-users-nofile.conf](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/root/commit/5e3cba7d73176ce28f166553ec7537307ffea2c7), but afterwards I was no longer allowed to log in. After seeing other people having the same issue I ended up booting from an alternative medium and changing the value back, but I'm none the wiser about **what the actual maximum `nofile` value is.**

Comment: See if this helps: http://www.linuxvox.com/post/what-are-file-max-and-file-nr-linux-kernel-parameters/

Comment: @kevlinux As far as I can tell `nofile` is not related to `file-max` or `file-nr` in any way. If that's wrong can you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: What distro/version are you using? Sorry, I'm not familiar with the config file. The referenced link discusses the actual limitations and reasoning, which is what I was addressing.

Comment: Arch Linux. As far as I can tell the linked article discusses some other limitations, hence my comment.

Answer (score -1):

On my Ubuntu 20.04 the limit for `nofile` is (2^20):

```
*                hard    nofile          1048576
```

Oddly if I add 1 the number falls to 524288 (2^19).

This limit is per process. The total limit for all processes is 2^63-1:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
9223372036854775807
```

The number of files currently opened is first column of:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
74144   0       9223372036854775807
```

On my server I have run:

```
ulimit -n 1048576
open_files() { perl -E 'for(1..'$1') { open($f{$_},"<","/dev/null") || die $_;} say "Done"; sleep 10000'; }
export -f open_files
seq 20000 | time parallel --nice 10 -uj0 open_files 30000
```

This runs with no problems and opens 600M files:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
600320672       0       9223372036854775807
```

So the practical limit is clearly higher.

Comment: That's just the current limit, not the system maximum.